# Unable to track upload progress with HttpURLConnection as well as OkHttp

Tags: android, upload, httpurlconnection, progress, okhttp

For some reason `HttpURLConnection` appears to be buffering the upload data no matter what I try. I can show the progress percentage of the data, but it is clear that the progress advances way too fast while the data is not flowing at that high rate.

The receiving server is not in the intranet, but hosted somewhere. The edge router is throttling the upload bandwidth to 2mbit in order to simulate a slow network, and in the bandwidth graph of the router I can see the data rate graph for the development device. The WiFi AP also allows me to see a graph of the data rate, and it looks just like the one of the edge router, so no device in the intranet is buffering the data. It is definitely the development device (Nexus 5X)

The following is the code that is being used:

```
HttpURLConnection hucConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//hucConnection.setUseCaches(false); // does not solve the issue
//hucConnection.setDefaultUseCaches(false); // does not solve the issue
//hucConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(true); // does not solve the issue
hucConnection.setConnectTimeout(6 * 1000);
hucConnection.setReadTimeout(30 * 1000);
hucConnection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
hucConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
hucConnection.setDoInput(true);
hucConnection.setDoOutput(true);

// Data to transfer
byte[] bData = joTransfer.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
int iDataLength = bData.length;

//hucConnection.setRequestProperty("content-transfer-encoding", "binary"); // does not solve the issue

// use compression
hucConnection.setRequestProperty("content-encoding", "deflate");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Deflater deflater = new Deflater(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
DeflaterOutputStream zip = new DeflaterOutputStream(stream, deflater);
zip.write(bData);
zip.close();
deflater.end();
byte[] bZippedData = stream.toByteArray();
Integer iZippedDataLength = bZippedData.length;


int iChunk = 1000;
hucConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(iChunk);
//hucConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(iZippedDataLength); // does not solve the issue
hucConnection.connect();

OutputStream osOutputStream = hucConnection.getOutputStream();

// FROM HERE ---->>>
int iUploadedLength;
for (iUploadedLength = 0; iUploadedLength < iZippedDataLength - iChunk; iUploadedLength += iChunk) {
    LogWrapper.e(TAG, "l -> f:" + iUploadedLength + " t:" + (iUploadedLength+iChunk));
    osOutputStream.write(Arrays.copyOfRange(bZippedData, iUploadedLength , iUploadedLength+iChunk));
    osOutputStream.flush();
}
LogWrapper.e(TAG, "r -> f:" + iUploadedLength + " t:" + iZippedDataLength);
osOutputStream.write(Arrays.copyOfRange(bZippedData, iUploadedLength, iZippedDataLength));
osOutputStream.flush();
osOutputStream.close();
// <<<---- TO HERE ---- XXXXXXXXX max 1 second XXXXXXXXX


// FROM HERE ---->>>
int iResponseCode = hucConnection.getResponseCode();
// <<<---- TO HERE ---- XXXXXXXXX about 10 seconds XXXXXXXXX

if (iResponseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
  ...
```

I expected the calls to `osOutputStream.flush();` to force the `HttpURLConnection` to send the data to the server, but for some reason that isn't happening.

It appears to get buffered somewhere, because after the `osOutputStream.close();` and before the `hucConnection.getResponseCode();` the data is getting uploaded to the server.

All the transfers (upload and download) are working properly, no data is damaged.

Is there a way to fix this, or an alternative to using HttpURLConnection? I've read that the `Socket` class does not have this problem, but I'm not sure if it handles redirects and stuff like that properly. I don't need to use cookies or some other stuff.

The aprox. 10 seconds it takes for `hucConnection.getResponseCode();` to finish is when about 3MB are uploaded (3MB*8b/B = 24Mb, 24Mb/2Mb/s = 12s), the data that is downloaded is getting sent after that call. The progress of the downloaded data is precise.

Is it possible that a 3rd party library is altering HttpURLConnection's behavior and doing some proxying? Like Firebase or something? I already disabled Crashlytics, but I think that Firebase also does some kind of stats gathering (response time). I think I had some strange issues about 1-2 months ago in another app, where I was getting a Proxy error issue in the domain name resolution, as if something inside of Android was proxying network traffic.

I'm about to give OkHttp a try, one of their recipies has a Post Streaming example (https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes)

Update: I implemented it using `okhttp3`, following the above mentioned recipie. I have the exact same problem there.

This is on Android 8.1

The server is an nginx instance.

I also ran the app on a Genymotion emulator instance, same OS, and it looks like it's better there, yet the problem still seems to be present, a bit. While radical throttling on the edge router has no effect on the Nexus 5X, it does have an effect on the emulator. But nonetheless, even the emulator upload tracking precision leaves much to be desired.

Would it make sense to use a WebSocket connection for that? That would be my last resort.

Answer (score -1):

The logic is for downloading used in AsyncTask, but I think, that it should be the same (just a switching input>output and so on)

```
InputStream inputStream = null;

try {
    try {
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(documentFile, false);

    try {
        inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
        long downloaded = 0;
        long target = dataLength;
        int readed;

        long updateSize = target / 10;
        long updateHelp = 0;

        while ((readed = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            downloaded += readed;
            updateHelp += readed;
            if (updateHelp >= updateSize) {
                updateHelp = 0;
                publishProgress(downloaded, target);
            }
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readed);
            if (isCancelled()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (inputStream != null) {
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I'm having problems with the upload progress, not the download progress. That one is working "precise". Also, I am in the background (`Observable` from `RxAndroid`) and where the `LogWrapper.e(...)` calls are, I'm emitting progress updates to the Main thread. User feedback is not the issue here.